# Ignore certain rows from an XML export in Excel?

Tags: excel, xml, export, rows

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I'd like to only export certain rows to XML (I'm using "Export" via the "Developer" tab). I tried to simply hide the rows, but they're still included in the outputted XML.

Comment: What happens if you filter the rows rather than hiding them? (I haven't tried this.) Otherwise, you may have to copy the data and delete the rows. But this is not a programming question and belongs elsewhere, such as the SuperUser forum.

Comment: @AndyG, I'm not sure what you mean; however, I think I may just use a new sheet for the rows to be ignored. If anyone has another solution, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a new sheet for the rows to be ignored.